# c#:Copy excel workbook to another

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2010

I have written code to get a copy of worksheets to a new excel file. Below is my C# code, the problem is some named cells are missing, and I have checked this in Excel-2010.

C# Code:

```
string strPath=@"C:\NewFolder\somexcelfile.xls";
Excel.Workbook souWorkbook = xCel.Workbooks.Open(strPath);
Excel.Workbook destWorkbook = xCel.Workbooks.Add();

foreach (Excel.Worksheet wkSheet in souWorkbook.Worksheets)
{
   wkSheet.Copy(destWorkbook.Worksheets[1]);
}
destWorkbook.SaveCopyAs("C:\NewFolder\copy.xls");
```

Comment: What is unique about the cells that are missing?

Comment: We have named cells in sheet,not like default A1,A2 s...cell names are like "Doc.A.1" etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to copy the named cells, you could use the following code sample

```
Sub Copy_All_Defined_Names()
   ' Loop through all of the defined names in the active
   ' workbook.
     For Each x In ActiveWorkbook.Names
      ' Add each defined name from the active workbook to
      ' the target workbook ("Book2.xls" or "Book2.xlsm").
      ' "x.value" refers to the cell references the
      ' defined name points to.
      Workbooks("Book2.xls").Names.Add Name:=x.Name, _
         RefersTo:=x.Value
   Next x
End Sub
```